# Creating a dynamic piecewise plot

Tags: function-construction, dynamic, piecewise

I'm trying to create a dynamic piecewise function. I can get 3 points, but after that, everything gets a bit complicated:

```
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{pts =  {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}}},
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
        Dynamic[Column[{Plot[
            Piecewise[{
                {x (y2 - y1)/( pts[[2, 1]] - pts[[1, 1]]), 
                pts[[1, 1]] <= x < pts[[2, 1]]},
                {x (y3 - y2)/(pts[[3, 1]] - pts[[2, 1]]) + (y2 - y1)/( 
                pts[[2, 1]] - pts[[1, 1]]) - (y3 - y2)/(pts[[3, 1]] - 
                pts[[2, 1]]), pts[[2, 1]] <= x < pts[[3, 1]]}
           }],
        {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> Large],
            Piecewise[{{x (y2 - y1)/(pts[[2, 1]] - pts[[1, 1]]),   pts[[1, 1]] <= x < 
            pts[[2, 1]]}, {x (y3 - y2)/(pts[[3, 1]] - pts[[2, 1]]) 
            + (y2 - y1)/(pts[[2, 1]] - pts[[1, 1]]) - (y3 - y2)/(pts[[3, 1]] 
            - pts[[2, 1]]), pts[[2, 1]] <= x < pts[[3, 1]]}}]}]],       
        Appearance -> None]],
{y1, 0, 2}, {{y2, 1}, 0, 2, Appearance -> None}, {{y3, 2}, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[toPW]
toPW[pts_, x_] := Piecewise[{#[[2]] + (#2/# & @@ Subtract@##) (x - #[[1]]), #[[1]] <= 
      x <= #2[[1]]} & @@@ Partition[SortBy[First]@pts, 2, 1]]

DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
  Dynamic[Plot[toPW[pts, x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> 3, 
    Exclusions -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
    PlotLabel -> toPW[pts, x]]], 
  LocatorAutoCreate -> True]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Plot[toPW[pts, x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> 3, Exclusions -> None, 
    Frame -> True, Axes -> False,  PlotLabel -> toPW[pts, x]], 
 {{pts, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}}}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

[image]

Comment: amazing - thank you